# WebBrowser Control Receives Javascript Error When Simulating Click Or Enter Key...Works When Clicking Or Pressing Enter

Tags: c#, .net, automation, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to automate logging into a particular site.  It seems like a typical form with two text inputs (username, password) and a button of type 'submit'.  All three have ids so I can easily call GetElementById for each.

My Code looks similar to this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("Value", "myUser");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("Value", "myPass");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submitButton").InvokeMember("Click");
```

This (sorta) works.  The values get set, and the form does submit/request is sent to the server.  But I immediately get a javascript error.  If I remove the 'Click' line and let my program load the page/populate the username/password and I manually click on the button - everything works 100%.

Okay I thought....I don't need to click.  I can just use the Keyboard!  Three tabs followed by enter successfully logs me in.  So I tried to use SendKeys.Send()

```
Thread.Sleep(250);
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
Thread.Sleep(250);
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
Thread.Sleep(250);
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
Thread.Sleep(250);
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Originally it was one line, I introduced the delays while debugging but to no avail.  The code above produces the exact same result as when I do the automated click - a javascript error and the following page does not load.

But if I press tab,tab,tab,enter - it does work.

I went one step further, if keep the SendKeys.Send("{TAB}") code, my automation program will fill the username/password and successfully navigate focus to the submit button.  If I press enter on the keyboard, no javascript error and everything is great.  But if I use SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") - nothing works.

I was under the impression that SendKeys.Send generated a 'real' keypress as far as the Windows OS is concerned?

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how I can get this login to work with the WebBrowser control?

Comment: I've successfully automated the login using WatiN (http://watin.org/) but I'd still be curious if anyone has an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to guess, but try it like this:

```
async Task SendSomeKeys()
{
  await Task.Delay(250);
  SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
  await Task.Delay(250);
  SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
  await Task.Delay(250);
  SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
  await Task.Delay(250);
  SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
}
```

The difference is, you'd send keys asynchronously this way, giving the browser a chance to process Windows messages between keystrokes (unlike with `Thread.Sleep`). So, it'd be more close to manual actions. If that works, the same approach may work for `SetAttribute`/`InvokeMember`.